# mySQL partitioning and combined indexes

Tags: mysql

I'm running a table that has built up to 600 million rows and is rapidly growing, which has been slowing down queries that need to run as quickly as possible. Current schema is:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_history` (
  `userId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `asin` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `dateSent` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  KEY `userId` (`userId`,`asin`,`dateSent`),
  KEY `dateSent` (`dateSent`,`asin`),
  KEY `asin` (`asin`,`dateSent`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Everything I've read about partitioning suggested that this was a prime candidate for partitioning by date range. We only tend to use the last 14 days data, but the client doesn't want to delete old data. The new schema looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_history_partitioned` (
  `userId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `asin` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `dateSent` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`dateSent`,`asin`,`userId`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
PARTITION BY RANGE ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dateSent) ) (
PARTITION Apr2013 VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-05-01')),
etc...
PARTITION Mar2014 VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-04-01')),
PARTITION Apr2014 VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-05-01')),
PARTITION May2014 VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-06-01')),
PARTITION Future VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE);
```

The idea of the Future partition is because a REORGANIZE PARTITION run on a populated partition was taking a long time to complete. So Future will always be empty and can reorganized into new partitions instantly. And other queries using this table have been reordered to use the primary key only, to reduce the number of indexes on the table.

The time-critical query is apropos of:

```
 SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE *
 FROM books B
 WHERE (non-relevant stuff deleted)
 AND NOT EXISTS
 (
     SELECT 1 FROM user_history H 
     WHERE 
     H.userId=$userId
     AND H.asin=B.ASIN
     AND dateSent > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY)
 )
 AND (non-relevant stuff deleted)
 LIMIT 1
```

So we're avoid duplicates that have already been selected for the same user in the last 14 days. And this currently returns in < 0.1 secs, which is okay but slower than it used to be on the current schema.

For the new schema, the inner SELECT has been reordered to:

```
SELECT 1 FROM user_history_partitioned H 
WHERE dateSent > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY)
AND H.asin=B.ASIN
AND H.userId=$userId
```

And it's taking 5 minutes per query. and I can't see why. The idea is that the current partition and indexes should be in memory (or maybe the previous month too, at some times of the month), and the primary index covers the WHERE clause. But from the time it's taking, it could be performing a full table scan on asin or userId. Which is difficult to identify from EXPLAIN because it's an inner query.

What am I missing? Do I need another combined index for (asin, userID)? If so, why?

Thanks,

PS: Tried wrapping the DATE_SUB(...) as UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(...)) just in case it was a type conversion issue, but made no difference.